# Strange behaviour, when using powershell Start-Process on local computer with credentials

Tags: powershell, credentials, start-process

I have task in windows scheduler. It runs powershell script ScriptScheduler.ps1 under Domain\User1.
This script run another one GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects.ps1 with credential Domain\User2.
When i am run it interactively under Domain\User1, everything ok. But with schedule i am see process started and nothing happend. Transcribe file for second script not created. The only thing i am get,event 26 in the application log, error about powershell start 0xc0000142.

```
GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects.ps1 start code:

Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ArgumentList -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –Noprofile  -file "C:\DATA\ProjectServices\SetProjectPermissions\SCRIPTS\GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects.ps1" -Verb RunAs -Credential $Credentials -PassThru
```

```
Transcript ScriptScheduler.ps1

**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20200422212501
Username: Domain\User1
RunAs User: Domain\User1
Machine: TEST-PC (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –Noprofile -file C:\DATA\Projects\ScriptScheduer\SCRIPTS\ScriptScheduler.ps1
Process ID: 5980
PSVersion: 5.1.14409.1018
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14409.1018
BuildVersion: 10.0.14409.1018
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\DATA\Projects\ScriptScheduler\LOGS\Transcript.log
Logging initialized.
Script scheduler started.
Run script @{Name=GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects; Path=C:\DATA\ProjectServices\SetProjectPermissions\SCRIPTS\GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects.ps1; UserName=Domain\User2; Credentials=System.Management.Automation.PSCredential; LogFile=C:\DATA\Projects\ScriptScheduler\LOGS\Daily.log; Evaluate=True; WorkDir=C:\DATA\ProjectServices\SetProjectPermissions\SCRIPTS} with evaluate.

GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects

Handles NPM(K) PM(K) WS(K) CPU(s)   Id SI ProcessName
------- ------ ----- ----- ------   -- -- -----------
             0     0     0        5592


Processing results.
Seconds run: [2.446404], task count: [1], task name: [GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects] errors count: [0].
Script scheduler exited.
PS>$global:?
True
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200422212503
**********************
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ...

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ArgumentList -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –Noprofile  -file "C:\DATA\ProjectServices\SetProjectPermissions\SCRIPTS\GenerateAndApplyACLforMultipleProjects.ps1" -Verb RunAs -Credential $Credentials -PassThru
```

... is the wrong way to run a scheduled task. Unless $credentials are already in memory when you run this, $credentials are empty.

> [Running PowerShell commands and scripts via ST is a well documented
>   and regularly used use case.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20scheduled%20task&form=ANSPH1&refig=88c205fc3b6f4c2db337fa04791a1b7c&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20scheduled%20ta&sc=8-23&qs=n&sk=&cvid=88c205fc3b6f4c2db337fa04791a1b7c)

[You can use the ST GUI to set this up and ensure you select the right identity to use, or use PowerShell to create the ST. [Video]](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20schedueld%20task)

Docs ---

> [New-Scheduled Task - learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask)
>
> [Set-Scheduled Task - learn.microsoft.com](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20scheduled%20task&form=ANSPH1&refig=88c205fc3b6f4c2db337fa04791a1b7c&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20scheduled%20ta&sc=8-23&qs=n&sk=&cvid=88c205fc3b6f4c2db337fa04791a1b7c)